# how to convert array elements from string to int in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a column in the table as jsonb `[14,21,31]` 
and I want to get all the rows with selected element eg

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_customers 
WHERE tags ?| array['21','14']
```

but the jsonb elements are in integer format
how do i convert the sql array elements into integer
i tried removing the quotes from the array but it gives an error

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: but you can't use an `int[]` as the right hand value for the `?|` operator - that requires a `text[]`

Comment: It would be a lot easier (and probably more efficient) if you stored those integers in an `int[]` column rather than a `jsonb`

Comment: is there any other operator that i can use instead of  ?| to match int[] @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Not with JSON arrays. As I said: this would better be stored in a native Postgres array

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution would be:

```
t=# with t_customers(tags) as (values('[14,21,31]'::jsonb))
select
  tags
, translate(tags::text,'[]','{}')::int[] jsonb_int_to_arr
, translate(tags::text,'[]','{}')::int[] @> array['21','14']::int[] includes
from
t_customers;
     tags     | jsonb_int_to_arr | includes
--------------+------------------+----------
 [14, 21, 31] | {14,21,31}       | t
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html 
if you want to cast as array - you should use `@>` operator to check if contains.

(at first I proposed it because I misunderstood the question - so it goes the opposite way, "turning" jsonb to array and checking if it contains, but now maybe this naive approach is the shortest)

the right approach here probably would be:

```
t=# with t_customers(tags) as (values('[14,21,31]'::jsonb))
, t as (select tags,jsonb_array_elements(tags) from t_customers)
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_array_elements::text) ?| array['21','14'] tags from t group by tags;
 tags
------
 t
(1 row)
```

which is basically "repacking" jsonb array with text representations of integers